# RxJava does not use all the threads in a Scheduler while parallel processing

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, rx-java

RxJava task was provided with a scheduler containing 20 threads. It is not using all the threads.

The code block

```
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

List<Integer> list = IntStream.range(1, 20).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Iterable<Integer> iterable = Flowable.fromIterable(list)
    .parallel()          
    .runOn(Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20)))
    .map(i -> {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " - i = " + i);
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(i % 5);
        return i * i;
    })
    .sequential()
    .blockingIterable();
list = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

The output, using only 4 threads. The Scheduler contains 20 threads.

```
pool-1-thread-1 - i = 1
pool-1-thread-5 - i = 2
pool-1-thread-4 - i = 4
pool-1-thread-3 - i = 3
pool-1-thread-1 - i = 5
pool-1-thread-1 - i = 9
pool-1-thread-5 - i = 6
pool-1-thread-5 - i = 10
pool-1-thread-5 - i = 14
pool-1-thread-3 - i = 7
pool-1-thread-4 - i = 8
pool-1-thread-1 - i = 13
pool-1-thread-3 - i = 11
pool-1-thread-3 - i = 15
pool-1-thread-3 - i = 19
pool-1-thread-4 - i = 12
pool-1-thread-5 - i = 18
pool-1-thread-1 - i = 17
pool-1-thread-4 - i = 16
[1, 25, 4, 36, 9, 100, 16, 81, 49, 121, 225, 196, 64, 169, 144, 256, 289, 324, 361]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `parallel()` from doc:

> creating multiple 'rails' (equal to the number of CPUs)

And doc about `runOn`:

> Note that the rails don't execute in parallel on their own and one
>   needs to apply ParallelFlowable.runOn(Scheduler) to specify the
>   Scheduler where each rail will execute.

So your actuall parallelism is equal number of cpus. Just use `parallel(int parallelism)`

Comment: Thank you very much @zella, the solution works perfect.